# How do cantrip improvements work when multiclassing?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, multi-classing, cantrips

I'm currently playing a D&D 5e campaign. My character is an Artificer/Cleric multiclass.
I was wondering if cantrips work off of a character's class level, or a character's total level, since cantrips are going to be very important due to my limited number of spell slots.

Comment: Welcome to the stack, Cadance! I've closed your question as a duplicate - which is totally fine! It's a good question and this allows another path for people to find an answer to it in the future. If you don't think it's a duplicate please let us know what's different and we can vote to reopen if necessary.

Comment: And please also visit our [tour] for information on how the stack operates and you can also check out the [help] to dive even deeper. Game on!

Comment: Hey y'all - new user. Let's not downvote because they didn't search the site first.